# Is it possible to change the version of Swift Xcode is using?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Running "swift -version" reveals that:

Xcode 8.2.1 is using Swift 3.0.2

BUT

Xcode 8.3 Beta is using Swift 3.0.

This is a nuisance as Realm has different Swift frameworks for 3.0 and 3.0.2 - which means using a project created with Xcode 8.2.1 using the Realm framework for 3.0.2 won't build if using Xcode 8.3.

Is there a way to change Xcode 8.3 beta to use Swift 3.0.2?

Comment: Note that Xcode 8.3 beta's Swift version printout is incorrect (this is [mentioned in the release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3_beta/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8.3_beta.pdf)) – it should say Swift 3.1. This may also affect compiler directives such as `#if swift(>=3.1)`.

Comment: In which case Realm 3.0.2 should work, but there's a compile error and instead the 3.0 framework has to be used. The Xcode beta is probably therefore still buggy regarding swift versions in more ways than just what the version printout.